# graphql-java: DataFetchEnvironment coming in as null on query resolver

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm using graphql with java on the server side and graphql/apollo with javascript on the client side. Generally I am very happy with the setup, but most recently I am stuck on an issue with the DataFetchingEnvironment.

I have two graphql queries which are being called identically on the client side. On the server side, the resolver methods take in the DataFetchingEnvironment as a parameter in order to get the context and retrieve a value from a cookie being passed in.

The one query executes flawlessly and the cookie value is read. On the other query, the DataFetchingEnvironment is coming in as null.

I'm puzzled as to why this is happening. Are there any reasons or conditions under which a graphql-java resolver method is not supposed to receive a Data Fetching Environment? Any ideas as to why this may be?

Here are my pom dependencies to show version numbers.

```
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>

        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>

        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>

        <groupId>com.zhokhov.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-datetime-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
```

Here is a skeletal version of the offending resolver method:

```
    public List<Something> getSomething( String somethingId, DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment ) {
        log( dataFetchingEnvironment ); // result is null
    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: @Vinnie I don't remember the exact details, but it was definitely a problem with the way resolver overloading and optional fields are resolved. My best advice is this: carefully review your queries/resolvers to make sure everything is painfully clear to GraphQL. It gets confused easily. Try to avoid overloading the methods and make sure which singular method is handling the query is painfully clear--because it seems pretty easily for the graphql resolution process to get confused and think the data fetch environment parameter is something else.

Comment: Thank you for responding @Mark.  I think was was doing it wrong - but as it turns out I didn't need it anyway.